# Google Scholar: Will having HTML and PDF in different subdirectories lead to incorrect indexing?

Tags: google-scholar

I am trying to get our department's green OA repo at my university's web-site properly indexed by Google Scholar.

The PDFs in our repo for a large part legacy scans with no structure. This means that there is little hope of Google being able to scrape usable metadata from the PDF, so having an HTML abstract with metadata linked to the PDF is in our case essential for providing Google Scholar with the correct metadata.

Our repo is based upon on the Drupal 7 CMS: The author fills in the Google Scholar Metadata, which is stored as a regular Drupal node (HTML), and then uploads the full length PDF to the site.  The PDF is stored in the server's file system.

The way Drupal works means that the URL of the HTML abstract becomes `http://example.org/node/NNN`, while the uploaded PDF will have an URL like `http://example.org/sites/default/files/XXXXXXX.pdf`. The two are then linked together through the `citation_pdf_url` metatag in the HTML.

I was happy with this, until I spotted the following paragraph in section H of the [Indexing Guidelines](http://scholar.google.no/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#indexing)  for Google Scholar:

> The content of the [`citation_pdf_url`] tag is the absolute URL of the PDF file; for security reasons, it must refer to a file *in the same subdirectory* as the HTML abstract. (my emphasis)
>
> *Failure to link the alternate versions together could result in the incorrect indexing of the PDF files, because these files would be processed as separate documents without the information contained in the meta tags.* (their emphasis)

Given that this means what I think it means, indexing of my repo will break as `node/`  is indeed not the same "subdirectory" as `sites/default/files/`.

However, who keeps HTML *content* in *subdirectories* in 2014?  The current webdesign paradigm is to separate content (such text rendered with HTML) from assets (such as PDF files), and only the latter is actually stored in the file system. To me, this requirements is outdated and will also probably break almost every repo that is built on some sort of CMS.

I am prepared to bite the bullet and write the code that is needed in order to spew out static HTML files that can be saved in the `sites/default/files/` subdirectory along with the PDF - if that is what it really takes to make Google Scholar index my repo.

However, before embarking upon this task, I wanted to hear from other that have repos that provide metadata for Google Scholar if this "same subdirectories" is absolutely *required* if you want the HTML abstract and full length PDF to be linked by means of `citation_pdf_url` tag.

Will having HTML and the PDF in different subdirectories really lead to incorrect indexing or no indexing of the PDF files?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about search engine optimisation. [webmasters.se] might take this.

Comment: No , this is not about SEO. It is about what precisely is required to be indexed by Google Scholar.  It can only be answered by someone that is familiar with Google Scholar. Those people are here, and not on the Webmasters site.  (Nor is this about programming.  I *know* how to program something that creates static HTML on the fly.  The question is whether this is necessary.)

Comment: I did search of "Google Scholar" on  Webmasters SE and found a few Q&As. I believe there are indeed some experts there.

Comment: I did search Webmasters, Stack Overflow and this site for questions about Google Scholar before posting.  *All of them* have questions about Google Scholar, but I found this site to have the most knowledgeable users.  That's why I posted here.  I guess I'll have to move on (probably to Stack Exchange) if it gets closed here, but I still have my best hopes for this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Scholar is pretty smart about these things.  On all of the websites I'm involved with, we keep the PDFs in a separate directory from the page that links to them, and Scholar finds them just fine.  Of course, we also don't us the `citation_pdf_url` tag, so maybe we're fine because we're low-tech and Scholar does the inference for us...

I recommend doing it the easy way, and trusting Scholar to be smart.  If it *doesn't* do the right thing, then you can always go back and drop the tag and wait for a refresh.  And then if *that* doesn't work, you can do it the hard way.

Comment: Unfortunately, Google Scholar is not smart enough to scrape metadata from our PDF scans :-( .  However, since this is closed now, I guess this answer is the best one.  Cheers!